# UIWebView ... What HTML format is required?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview

I'm loading blog posts from a SQL database into a UIWebView. The posts aren't rendering correctly.  I went into the database.  The data does have html tags, but not <html> <body>

Do I have to inject these tags to get data to render?

Comment: It needs to be a proper HTML document as you would have in any web browser

Comment: So @SamiKuhmonen.  You are loading an actual Web Page?

Answer (score 1):

The docs state that UIWebView can display "HTML content", by which I assume it means *valid* HTML content.
I would ensure that the HTML document you are trying to display is able to display in Safari or some other browser.

Note, as suggested in [Apple's UIWebView doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) that since iOS 8, [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) is preferred for new development:

> NOTE
>
> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead
>   of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences
>   property javaScriptEnabled to NO if you render files that are not
>   supposed to run JavaScript.